# Confused on usage and meaning of 'context' in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am a fresh intern who has just completed my first year of college. I took two intro to comp sci classes and have a fairly solid fundamental knowledge of Java but also basic OOP language ideas. I have never used C# before and my internship requires it. My task has been to start a MVC application that does some basic task but I am confused on the usage of 'context' in this situation. I am using Microsoft Virtual Studio with the ASP.NET MVC blank template. Here is where I find 'context' to be used. I am mainly confused on how or why it is being used in this method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Use

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you hit F12 on the method `Run()`?

Comment: In your example, `context` is simply the name of a variable. My guess is that `context` contains a reference to an instance of the [HttpContext class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8) that represents the HTTP transaction that is currently in flight. `IApplicationBuilder.Run()` promises to pass the instance to your delegate, which is why it is included in the lambda expression.

Comment: I feel like I understand why context is used and what an Iambda method is. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
```

Tells ASP.NET Core to "Run" a middleware.  Running a middleware means, given an `HttpContext`, read the request and write the result-- as opposed to "using" a middleware which means the middleware might execute or might defer execution to the next middeware in the chain.  This is specific to ASP.NET Core, not C#.

The `app.Run()` method expects a delegate in the form of an async function that takes a single `HttpContext` parameter.  The lamda expression `(context)=> { }` is shorthand for an anonymous function with a single parameter named `context`.  The C# compiler recognizes the type of `context` based on the expected prototype.  You might write that code like this:

```
app.Run(helloWorldHandler);
...

private async Task helloWorldHandler(HttpContext context) {
   await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
}
```